# Checking if a path of drive is exists, not drive letter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if the path of network drive I wants to map is already exists in the computer drives, and if yes - it will not be able to map it.
I read about the `Directory.Exists()` that helps me to achieve it, but what I only achieve with it is to show me the avilable drives on the computer.
So, now, my code can get all the Drives' letters that avilable and not taken yet, but I'm still not able to check if the path is already mapped. **For example, user wants to map a network drive with path of "\server\x\y\z" - How I can check if the path is already mapped in this computer?** Any suggestions?

Comment: What if the user requests `\server\x\y\z` but `\server\x` is already mapped? You also have tagged this question ASP.NET, you can't access the user's filesystem from a web server, you realise that?

Comment: You need a desktop application for that.

Comment: Because on your development machine the site runs under your account, and your machine is the server. Drive mappings are per machine and per user. When deployed, the site runs on another machine, under another account. It won't affect the client machine.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you very much. Will defintly save me alot of time and effort. So what should I choose on Visual Studio? Windows Form app .net or ASP.NET Web application?

Comment: That would a WinForms application.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use Directory.Exists() to get what you are after if I read your question correctly.

Simply pass a string parameter for the drive you wish to map to into Directory.Exists in an If statement and it will return the answer.

There are some user permission/access issues around this regarding networked drives I believe